# gazebosim.org down

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems the website gazebosim.org is down. Are people at OSRF aware?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186981/gazebosim.org-down/) by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4306 on 2014-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems to be back up.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0